# How to set d3.layout.force.charge once d3.layout.force has already been initialized?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

What I want to do is onClick, change the charge so that nodes are repelled by a higher force, but this is not working:

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .gravity(.05)
    .charge(function(d, i) { return i ? 0 : -2000; })
    .nodes(nodes)
    .size([w, h]);

svg.on("click", function() {
  force = force.charge(function(d, i) { return i ? 0 : -10000; })
  window.setTimeout(function() {
  force = force.charge(function(d, i) { return i ? 0 : -2000; })
  },3000);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you have to do is call force.start which runs through the declared nodes again and changes the charges and other properties on them.

```
svg.on("click", function() {
  force = force.charge(function(d, i) { return i ? 0 : -50000; })
  force.start()
  window.setTimeout(function() {
  force = force.charge(function(d, i) { return i ? 0 : -2000; })
  force.start()
  },3000);
});
```

Comment: That didn't take you long to figure out. Note that technically you're supposed to call `force.restart()`.

Comment: there is no force.restart() method, but if you mean force.resume(), that doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: Good catch, yes, should have been `.resume()`. And ok, if that doesn't work in this case...